# Start elevated Powershell session with multiline string arguments

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass a script block as a command to run when I start an elevated powershell session, but I can't find a way to make it work. I think it's because the file contents is multiline?

```
$content = @"
This is a
multiline
file content.
"@

$path = 'C:\test.txt'

$scriptBlock = {
    param($fileContent, $filePath)
    Write-Host "PATH: $filePath`n`n"
    Write-Host "CONTENT:`n$fileContent"
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($filePath, $fileContent, [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('Windows-1252'))
    Pause
}

Start-Process -FilePath 'PowerShell' -Verb 'RunAs' -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command '&{$scriptBlock} `"$content`" `"$path`"'" -Wait

Pause
```

What am I missing? Is there a better way to achieve this?

I tried the above code, but the elevated Powershell session simply closes right after it opens. I think the Start-Process line is wrong.

**EDIT:**

I tried wrapping the script block contents with a function and changed the Start-Process a little bit, and now it works:

```
$content = @"
This is a
multiline
file content.
"@

$path = 'C:\test.txt'


$scriptBlock = {
    function wrappingFunc {
        param(
            $filePath,
            $fileContent
        )

        Write-Host "PATH: $filePath"
        Write-Host "CONTENT: $fileContent"
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($filePath, $fileContent, [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('Windows-1252'))
        Pause
    }
}

Start-Process -FilePath 'PowerShell' -Verb 'RunAs' -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command & {$scriptBlock wrappingFunc -filePath '$path' -fileContent '$content'}" -Wait

Pause
```

I actually don't completely understand why it works like this though. Can someone clarify?

I also noticed a very weird behaviour. If I change the following lines inside the script block from:

```
    Write-Host "PATH: $filePath"
    Write-Host "CONTENT: $fileContent"
```

to:

```
    Write-Host -Object "PATH: $filePath"
    Write-Host -Object "CONTENT: $fileContent"
```

it stops working. Why does simply adding `-Object` breaks it?

Comment: Try adding -noexit to your powershell arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>[1] Also note [zdan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4304/zdan)'s helpful debugging tip: Temporarily add `-NoExit` before `-Command` in your PowerShell CLI call to keep the session open, which allows you to inspect error messages.</sup>

**The problem isn't the use of a *multiline* command string, it is related to *quoting***:

- Don't use `'...'`-quoting in the `-Command` argument (unless those `'` characters are part of the PowerShell code to execute) - when called *from the outside* - which using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) is an example of - PowerShell treats a `'...'` string on its *process command line* as a *verbatim string*.

  - From outside PowerShell (including when calling from `cmd.exe` or from a scheduled task, for instance), when calling its CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+) ) only `"..."` quoting has *syntactic* function (on the process command line).
- Escape `"` characters that are to become part of the PowerShell command to execute as `\"` - otherwise PowerShell's initial *CLI* parsing will remove them.

**Making your code work *robustly*** based on these requirements is somewhat cumbersome (a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) is used for quoting convenience and readability):

```bash
# ...

Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell -Verb RunAs -Wait -ArgumentList @"
  -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "
    & {
      $($scriptBlock -replace '(\\*)"', '$1$1\"')
    } '$($content -replace '(\\*)"', '$1$1\"' -replace "'", "''")' '$($path -replace "'", "''")'
  "
"@
```

- The `-replace` operations ensure that any `"` chars. that are part of the variable values referenced are escaped as `\"` to protect them from the initial CLI parsing.

  - `(\\*)` in the regex captures any `\` characters immediately preceding a `"` in the values, which must be *doubled* in order to preserved as such, which is what `$1$1` in the substitution expression does.
- In the case of `$content` and `$path`, because embedded `'...'` quoting is used, any embedded `'` chars. must additionally be escaped as `''` (since file paths on Windows cannot contain `"` chars., the `$paths` value needs *only* this escaping.

  - Using embedded `'...'` quoting rather than `"..."` ensures that the values of `$content` and `$replace` aren't subject to *another* round of interpolation in the target PowerShell instance.

**Important**:

- The above is designed to handle *any values* in `$scriptBlock`, `$content` and `$path` - *situationally* you may *get away with* NOT
  performing the `-replace` operations, but you need to fully understand the rules to know when - and for that reason the Base64 solution presented in the next section is preferable.
- Enclosing the PowerShell code passed to `-Command` in `"..."` overall isn't strictly needed, but *not* doing so has the side effect of *whitespace normalization* (which often *won't* be a problem, but can be); e.g., if `$content` contained `Four spaces:    ...`, it would turn into `Four spaces: ...`. That is, any run of *two or more spaces* would turn into a *single* space.
- Even if you do not use overall `"..."` enclosure, `"` characters that are part of the PowerShell code to execute *must* be escaped as `\"`
- The above explains the - brittle - behavior of the code you later added to your question, in the "EDIT:" section:

  - While the updated code avoids the primary problem with your *original* attempt, by removing the mistaken overall `'...'` enclosure, it is still subject to the removal of unescaped `"` characters, which explains the problem with your attempt to add `-Object` to the `Write-Host` call:

    - Due to the removal of `"` chars., `` Write-Host -Object "PATH: $filePath`n`n" `` turned into `` Write-Host -Object PATH: $filePath`n`n ``, which causes a *syntax* error, because the use of *named* parameter binding with `-Object` only accepts a *single* argument (which, however, may be a `,`-separated *array* of values), but the `"` removal turned the single argument into *multiple* ones. (Only if you use *positional* parameter binding, i.e. *without* `-Object`, does `Write-Host` does accept *multiple, individual* arguments, which is why - despite the `"` removal - it still *happens to work*.)
  - The code would also break if your `$content` and `$path` values contained `'` chars.

---

If you want to ***avoid* the quoting headaches and `-replace` operations**, you can  **Base64-encode** your script block as well as the arguments and use the results with the **`-EncodedCommand`** and (currently undocumented) **`-EncodedArguments`** CLI parameters instead:

```bash
# ... 

# Create a Base64 representation of the bytes that make up the
# "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) encoding of the script block, for use
# with the -EncodedCommand PowerShell CLI parameter.
# Note that $scriptBlock is implicitly *stringified* here, resulting
# in its verbatim source code, but without the enclosing { ... }
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
  [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($scriptBlock)
)

# Create a Base64 representation of the bytes that make up the
# "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) encoding of the - invariably positional -
# arguments to pass, for use with `-EncodedArguments`.
# Note the need to pass the arguments as an *array* (@(...)).
$encodedArgs = [Convert]::ToBase64String(
  [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes(
    [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize(@($content, $path))
  )
)

# Note the use of -EncodedCommand and -EncodedArguments
Start-Process -FilePath 'PowerShell' -Verb 'RunAs' -Wait -ArgumentList @"
  -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -EncodedCommand $encodedCommand -EncodedArguments $encodedArgs
"@
```

Note:

- Only *positional* argument-passing is supported this way; that is, you can pass, say, *values* `foo` and `c:\bar` to your script block's parameters, with the *order* of these values implying `-fileContent` and `-filePath` as the target parameters, but you cannot use `-fileContent foo` and `-filePath bar`, i.e. you cannot use *named* arguments.
- The only way to support *named* arguments would be to "bake" such named arguments into the script block via string interpolation rather than passing separate arguments, as in your updated attempt, but that again would require careful quoting and escaping.

Comment: this `-EncodedArguments` thing is a great deal, just like the `-EncodedCommand`. How do you know about it? I can't find documentation anywhere

Comment: @ThiagoRangel, yes, it's currently undocumented, unfortunately. Honestly, I don't remember how I learned about it; it is used _behind the scenes_ when you call the CLI from _inside_ PowerShell _with a script block_ and `-args` (try `powershell { [Environment]::CommandLine } -args one, two`). If you're adventurous, you can look at the source code; [start here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/65327256bf53d1e91457f0cf28780c26b088eda8/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/CommandLineParameterParser.cs#L1093).

Comment: why do you have to `Serialize` the array before encoding it? I'm asking because as I understand it, after the Base64 decoding, the result will be a CliXML string representing the original array. Does `-EncodedArguments` expect a CliXML string instead of the real array? As there's no documentation, I don't know which type `-EncodedArguments` expects. For example: according to the docs, `-EncodedCommand` "accepts a base-64-encoded string version of a command". Would `-EncodedArguments` "accept a base-64-encoded string of a CliXML-serialized argument" or something like that?

Comment: @ThiagoRangel, yes, your description of `-EncodedArguments` is correct (more specifically, "... of the bytes making up the UTF-16LE encoding of a CLIXML-serialized _array_ of positional arguments"). `-EncodedCommand`, by contrast, requires no intermediate format: you base Base64-encode (the UTF-16LE bytes of) the source code as-is; that source code becomes a script block to which the decoded arguments, if any, are positionally passed.

Comment: @ThiagoRangel, another thing worth mentioning: In the `[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($scriptBlock)` call, `$scriptBlock` is implicitly *stringified*, resulting in its verbatim source code, but without the enclosing `{ ... }` (try `{ Get-Date; 1 + 2 }.ToString()`, for instance); in other words: when passing a string directly, do _not_ enclose the source code it contains in `{ ... }`.